# jaxb unmarshal to custom class

Tags: java, jaxb

I try to unmarshal a xml file to custom classes via jaxb.

The (not changeable) xml file looks as follow:

```
<demo>
  <customers>
    <customer usrid="1" name="jane" />
    <customer usrid="2" name="leia" />
    <customer usrid="3" name="tobi" />
  </customers>
  <phonenumbers>
    <phonenumber usrid="1">123-456-789</phonenumber>
    <phonenumber usrid="2">987-654-321</phonenumber>
    <phonenumber usrid="2">111-222-333</phonenumber>
  </phonenumbers>
  <mobilenumbers>
    <mobilenumber usrid="3">666-666-666</mobilenumber>
  </mobilenumbers>
</demo>
```

Java classes look something special:

```
public class Demo {
  public List<Customer> customers;
}

public class Customer {
  public String usrid;
  public String name;
  public List<Number> numbers;
}

public class Number {
  public NumberType type;
  public String value;
}

public enum NumberType {
  phone, mobile
}
```

Is this possible with jaxb (e.g. adapter) or do i have to do a xslt transform first ?

Btw. using jaxb straightforward works fine (annotations omitted):

```
public class Demo {
  public List<Customer> customers;
  public List<Phonenumber> phonenumbers;
  public List<Mobilenumbers> mobilenumbers;
}

public class Customer {
  public String usrid;
  public String name;
}

public class Phonenumber {
  public String usrid;
  public String value;
}

public class Mobilenumber {
  public String usrid;
  public String value;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. JAXB is to match Java to XML structures more or less 1:1. Don't push transformation logic into JAXB.

Comment: Having said that, check `@XmlID`, `@XmlIDREF` and `com.sun.xml.bind.IDResolver` (not sure about the package name).

Comment: With `@XmlID`, `@XmlIDREF` i would have a `User` reference in the `Phonenumber`/`Mobilenumber` class correct ? But goal should be a overall number list in the `Customer` class ...